# How many different ways to connect two triangles exist?

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say you have two triangles with of side's lengths $a, b, c$ and $x, y, z$ respectively, such that all lengths  are different.

Two triangles are **connected** if they have one common vertex and two sides lie on one straight line.

**Question**

How many different ways to connect two triangles exist?

**Edit.** My answer is **54**.

Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $A_1$, $B_1$, $C_1$ be the vertex name of triangles $\Delta ABC$ and $\Delta A_1B_1C_1$ respectively.

One can fix the first triangle $\Delta ABC$ and connect vertices $A$ and $A_1$ such that sides $AC$ and $A_1C_1$ will lie on one straight line. 
One put the second triangle in three ways: a) outside, b) inside, c) near:

[image]

In three cases above one can rotate $3$ times the second triangle $\Delta A_1B_1C_1$ while the vertex $A$ is fixed. The triangle $\Delta ABC$ has the two vertices on each side, therefore, one can connect two triangles on one side by $3 \times 2$ ways. The fixed triangle has three sides, therefore, one can connect two triangles by $3 \times 2 \times 3 =18$ ways.

One can have three cases above, finally, $18 \times 3 =54$ ways.

**Edit 2.** After the @SheridanGrant's answer I added the case (d). 
And I thinking about the case (f). Should the case (f) give additional ways to the solution? Triangles have the same height.

[image]

Comment: Depends on what's considered different. $B$ could be on the same side of $A$ as $B_1$ is, or on the other side. Do those count as different?

Comment: OK. Anyway, you can rotate the 2nd triangle to three different positions, but you can also flip that triangle, so I get $36$ ways. Unless one side of the 1st triangle, say, $AB$, has the same length as one side of the 2nd triangle, say, $A'B'$. Then connecting $A$ and $A'$ with $B$ coinciding with $B'$ can't be distinguished from connecting $B$ and $B'$ with $A$ coinciding with $A'$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thank you for the comment, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a case--in case $c$, reflect the blue triangle over its bottom side. 4 cases, two edges at each side, 3 choices of vertex for first triangle, 3 choice of vertex for second triangle yield $4 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 3 = 72 = 54 \cdot \frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: (+1) for the answer. Do you have an idea of how to re-write a condition in order to exclude the case (c).

Comment: Replace "two sides lie on one straight line" with "one side contains the other" or "one side is a strict subset of the other." (Also, if you accept my answer, I get more internet points, which I am currently sorely lacking.)

Comment: after your answer, I added the case (d). And I thinking about the case (f). Should the case (f) give additional ways to the solution? Two triangles have the same height.

Comment: Case (f) doesn't always occur, and if the triangles are generated through some continuous random process such that no edge lengths are ever the same then it will in fact occur with probability zero. You could split your answer into cases or just note  this.